# mousedown and move cross dom element, keep cursor is crosshair

Tags: javascript, css

When mousedown and mouse move from outside to inside, the cursor become like text, how to keep cursor is crosshair?
I tried use `:active` but not work ..

https://jsfiddle.net/xu9tmmfr/

```css
div,
img {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
.a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <img class="c" src="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want ??

Comment: Works on chrome. What browsers did you test?

Comment: @DenisSheremet safari not work ...

Comment: Not sure though but may be try `img.c { display:block }`

Comment: @Novice not work I tried make div, img display block